# exists condition in a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm quite new to PL/SQL, sorry if the question is obvious

According to the [TRIGGER documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm), there is a WHEN ( condition ) for triggers. I wanted to use an [exists condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions012.htm#SQLRF52150), which  requires a subquery, however, I have the following error :

> ORA-02251
>
> 2251. 00000 -  "subquery not allowed here"
>
> *Cause:    Subquery is not allowed here in the statement.
>
> *Action:   Remove the subquery from the statement.

What did I miss?

My condition is the following :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mytrigger AFTER UPDATE OF column ON THIS_TABLE 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.status = 'approved' AND EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM JUNCTION_TABLE WHERE THIS_TABLE_ID=NEW.this_table_id AND OTHER_TABLE_ID = 'SOMETHING'))
DECLARE
BEGIN
END;
```

I want to check whether the row is associated to a given value, which I can only find in a junction table.

I could surely do this in the PL/SQL part of the trigger, but :

- it is related to the trigger rather than the business logic in itself
- I'd like to understand what I missed in the documentation and why it is not possible.

If another condition might do this, I'm also interested.

Comment: could you include the full trigger code in the question please

Comment: Done, but not useful, the other part works without the condition

Answer (score 0):

I would write this with the conditional element within the trigger itself, something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mytrigger AFTER UPDATE OF column ON THIS_TABLE 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.status = 'approved')

DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM JUNCTION_TABLE WHERE THIS_TABLE_ID=NEW.this_table_id AND OTHER_TABLE_ID = 'SOMETHING'))
...
END;
```

Comment: I think I should separate the "when do I activate" from the "what do you do", in order to be reusable. Or do you suggest I do a procedure  BEING IF EXISTS ... call another procedure END; ?

Comment: my preferred approach in the past has been to put all the "when do i activate" within the trigger (so remove the NEW.status,,, bit from the WHEN clause. I would only have another procedure if that is repeated cod ewhich could be called by another trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which Oracle documentation was used. Though the Oracle 10.2 documentation doesn't mention this, in the [Oracle 11.1 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS020) the limitation is mentioned:

> The expression in a WHEN clause must be a SQL expression, and it **cannot include a subquery**. You cannot use a PL/SQL expression (including user-defined functions) in the WHEN clause.

There's no alternative I can think of at the moment to checking the condition inside the trigger code, as mentioned.